# Does org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException exceptions regularly cause Connection closed issue?

Tags: jdbc, lucene

system is facing connection Socket closed issue and server is going down. Not happening daily, but happening some days after server startup. In the log we are only seeing exceptions related with org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException. Does the lucene parse exceptions cause connection close issues? No jdbc connections are used at lucene query parsing side. Please let us know your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Connection closed`means that *you* closed the connection and continued to use it, which is a bug in your code, and if this is causing your server to go down there is something **seriously** wrong with its exception handling.